# Software that prevents downloads from websites on workstations

Tags: sysadmin

I am a SaaS developer who has a popular website that services users in financial institutions. As we have grown i have noted that an increasing number of our end users are having downloads or uploads blocked due to corporate IT policies and / or software.

To help mitigate this issue we want to create a help article in our help center that outlines the common scenarios when this happens (e.g. you work at a bank, are on your work computer, you get this type of error).

What I don't know however is if there is specific (popular) software that would be on these computers that i can reference? (e.g. if you are running MalwareBytes do this..) - is there common software controlled by sysadmins that prevents downloads / uploads? or is it just group policies or specific config applied to browsers in a disk image or something?

Comment: We always just said "contact your IT department".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a standard as each IT shop typically runs their own stack of security software, be that firewalls, browser plugins, etc.

From the institutions I've worked with the most popular information to provide is to have the end user have their IT department "whitelist" the domain name, URL, or IP address (depending on the use case).

This is usually enough information for the IT staff to get started or at least have an indication of what to do.  I have also seen this in numerous FAQs on numerous products that face similar issues like the one described.  Most solutions that block by Domain/URL/IP have a whitelisting feature but not all do.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is our typical support response as well "have the user contact their IT team and whitelist [url], this should allow [whatever] to resume."

In some cases we hear (3rd hand usually) that they disabled a piece of software on their computer.   I've yet to get an actual name on what software it is.